# How gets size of char[] when i read from a text file

Tags: c++, char, txt

I'm reading a `.txt` file. I need to read at most 254 characters into my `char*` buffer, so I did this:

```cpp
char *buffer = new char[255];
***Some Code***
if (!feof(fichero))
{
    if (fgets(buffer, 254, fichero) != NULL)
    {
```

How do get the size of the buffer read? Right now I'm using a manual method to find `'\n'` and use its position as the size. But is there a better way?
My code for now:

```cpp
char *buffer = new char[255];
int tamanio;
***more code***
if (!feof(fichero))
{
    if (fgets(buffer, 254, fichero) != NULL)
    {
        //printarCadena(buffer);
        tamanio = limpiarBuffer(buffer);
        printf("Tamanio buffer: %i \n", tamanio);


int Gestor::limpiarBuffer(char* buffer)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < int(strlen(buffer));i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] == '\n')
            return i;
    }
    return int(strlen(buffer) - 1);
}
```

Edit: I`ve to use Char*, University vibes

Edit2: I've to read line by line, if line ve more than 255 characteres, i read as 2 or more lines

Comment: You are using c++. Why not use fstream instead of the C way to deal with files?

Comment: With `std::fstream` you can easelly read the file `for (std::string line; std::getline(file_stream, line); );`

Comment: Edit: I`ve to use Char*, University vibes

Comment: If this is one of *those* courses that completely and utterly fails to teach C++, but instead teaches "fancy C", then I hope you survive and do well, but please forget everything they tell you as soon as you're done the course.

Comment: Can you return `size_t` instead of doing bizarre things like `int(strlen(buffer) - 1)`?

Comment: Are you trying to read one line, or the entire file? If it's one line then you'll have precisely one line and the last character might be `\n`, so it's easy to snip off. If you're trying to read the entire file, then don't use `fgets` but `fread`, or even better, proper C++ functions from `ifstream`.

Comment: Whats differnce between cast to int size_t and not cast? Im just secure about i need int

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, as in you can't have negative file sizes or string lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int getSize(char* buffer)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < int(strlen(buffer));i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] == '\n')
            return i;
    }
    return strlen(buffer);
}
```

By now no other way to do with char*